# getter and setter and increment a variable

Tags: java, setter, getter

```
public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

Now if I have to increment the variable... which one is the way of doing ?

```
variables.setA(variables.getA()+1);
```

in this way a always is 1.

can i solve the problem?

Comment: add a method to your class `incrementA() {a++}`

Comment: Your code would increment 'a' by 1. Are you trying to find a better way?

Answer (score 7):

That code is correct (if verbose). The following:

```
public class Main {

    private int a = 0;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main variables = new Main();
        System.out.println(variables.getA());
        variables.setA(variables.getA()+1);
        System.out.println(variables.getA());
        variables.setA(variables.getA()+1);
        System.out.println(variables.getA());
        variables.setA(variables.getA()+1);
        System.out.println(variables.getA());
    }
}
```

prints

```
0
1
2
3
```

Given the verbosity of `variables.setA(variables.getA()+1)`, you might want to wrap it into a method (e.g. `incrementA()` or `addToA(int)` etc)

Answer (score 3):

Your way of incrementing a variable should work, but you could also define a new method:

```
public void incrementA(){
    a++;
}
```